# How to tell when a SSRS Data Driven Subscription has finished running in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report running against a Data Driven subscription in SSRS. The subscription runs a report and produces PDFs - about 1000 of them. The process takes about 2 minutes to complete.

I have been kicking this off manually using the following SQL:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = '<job_name>'
```

This works, but what I would like to know is when the job has finished. According to what I have read so far, I should be able to run:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job
```

This lists my job, but it always has a status of 4 (Idle), even while I can see that reports are being produced.

How can I tell when the job has completed and all my reports have been produced?

Comment: Refer to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

MSDB shouldn't contain informtaion on the reporting server. The reporting server is seperate from Sql Server Management Server and will only tell you if the job ran or not not what happened in the job. If you have access to the DB I don't know how you have it set up but I have a subscriptions table that I can check with email sent and when it was sent. IF you don't have that you can go onto the reportserver web site and check the subscription and check the status and it should have a date of when it was last sent.

The only way you can access the information in Sql Server Management Studio is by queryng the DB and its tables assuming it is setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need to be able to tell programmatically when the subscription has finished producing reports. If msdb doesn't contain the information, maybe the ReportServer does, but I can't find anything here.